# How to synchronize the threads in the time Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I study a thread and trying make a timer using thread. To the main thread wrote a time

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Please, write the time in ms");
        long time = Long.parseLong(reader.readLine());
        B thread = new B();

        int timer = 0;
        try {
            thread.start();
            Thread.sleep(time);
            timer=thread.stop();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Oh....");
        }
        System.out.println("Result is "+timer);
    }
}
```

and every millisecond program write a name of specific millisecond in child thread.

```
public class B implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean running=true;
    private int timer=0;
    Thread thread;

    public B() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            System.out.println(timer);
            timer++;
        try  {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)  {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
        }
    }
   public int stop() {
    running = false;
    return timer;
   }

    public void start() {
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

But when try with parameter 50 get the result 37. I want understand how to synchronize it in the time. Can you explain me how to do it correct?

Comment: Hint: what is the variable `running` supposed to do and where are you changing its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting that all the statements other than `Thread.sleep(1)` also take time to execute. Most notably the `System.out.println(timer)`: this is an I/O operation and whenever such an operation takes place, it usually sucks time (printing to screen makes the program wait for this blocking I/O operation to complete).

But I like to demonstrate a more subtle assumption: you also assume that when `thread.start()` returns, `B.run()` is executing. This is not the case, as is demonstrated in the following little program:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadTimer implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadTimer tt = new ThreadTimer();
        long afterStart = 0L;
        new Thread(tt).start();
        afterStart = System.nanoTime();
        println("After start: " + afterStart);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100L);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long deltaStart = tt.realStart - afterStart;
        println("Delta start: " + deltaStart);
        long deltaStartMs = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(deltaStart);
        println("Delta start ms.: " + deltaStartMs);
    }

    public long realStart;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        realStart = System.nanoTime();
        println("Real start : " + realStart);
    }
    private static void println(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

}
```

On my system this shows:

```
After start: 40062314666459
Real start : 40062314706827 
Delta start: 40368 
Delta start ms.: 0
```

Which means a little bit of time was lost. I'm sure that if you measure how long it takes to perform `System.out.println(timer)`, you will see more little bits of time lost. All these little bits eventually add up to quite a chunk of time not accounted for.

On a final note: `System.nanoTime()` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` also take time to execute (it takes time to measure the time).

Answer (score 1):

When time is over just set the variable `running` to false,it will end the while loop and the child thread will also be finished.

So after below line, try to set `running` variable to `false`.(provide some setter method or may be in constructor argument)

```
Thread.sleep(time);
```

Comment: Thank you! I try this 'public int stop() {
        running = false;
        return timer;
    }' and when try with parameter 50 get the result 817.

Comment: so it means in 50 ms your while loop executed 817 times..what's wrong with it? your time and timer are different variable.. If you want to get the result 50, I mean if you want your child thread should print 50,then put  one more Thread.sleep(//1ms) inside while loop.Thats' it. it should work.

Comment: Ok, so how it make, so when I wrote 50 the child thread wrote 50. I want understand how to synchronize it in the time, when added to loop ` Thread.sleep(1); ` result is 37